# Angular material checkbox started to pop out to top

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNyQm.png)

Do you have any idea why suddenly the checkbox upon click started to pop out of its container to top:-12px ?

I've tried to trace the click state but only noticed -12px set on the top, when exploring the computed layout tab in dev tools.

Any ideas would be appreciated.